# 2d array construction confusion in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am working on a lab for a class I'm taking and I'm reading the code provided by the teacher... I'm wondering if anyone here can make sense of this array construction (which is completely unrelated to the rest of the program, so no, you're not doing my homework for me :)

```
float **b = new float*[n]; //create local matrix
b[0] = new float[n*nCols];
for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) b[j] = b[j-1] + n;
```

To me, it looks like this will create a bunch of garbage based on whatever was in memory before b was created... There is no initialization of `b[0][0]` so it seems like this will generate unpredictable output.

Is that correct?

Also, as far as I can tell, this is the "shape" of the `b` array of array pointers:

```
b= {
     *{ ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, .... nCols unknown floats },
     *{ ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, .... nCols unknown floats },
     *{ ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, .... nCols unknown floats },
     *{ ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, .... nCols unknown floats },
     *{ ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, .... nCols unknown floats },
     ...
     n
   }
```

So `b` is an array of size `n` pointers to arrays of size `nCols`

Is this correct?

Doesn't this code seem a little more confusing than it should be, and probably incorrect (since it's using default-initialized garbage values)?

I'm new to C++ and I just want to make sure I'm understanding what I'm reading here. The teacher is used to Fortran and we're learning about parallel systems, so this isn't really related to class.

Thanks.

---

**EDIT** (update)

user2079303 pointed out that this line:
`for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)    b[j] = b[j-1] + n;`
(which should be:
`for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)    b[j] = b[j-1] + nCols;`
)

is setting up `b[x]` where `x > 0`, as an array of pointers to elements in a `n*nCols` matrix (stored at address `b[0]`) by doing pointer arithmetic with `b[j-1]`...

That makes sense to me now why this is all just garbage in this array. All this construction is doing is creating a bunch of pointers to a space in memory that will be used later.

In fact, as user2079303 surmised, the data is not read from these pointers until it's set but other processes:
`MPI_Scatter(a[0],n*nCols,MPI_FLOAT,b[0],n*nCols,MPI_FLOAT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);`

In that function the pointer to `b[0]` is a receive buffer! So the garbage is overwritten, not ever used, but the pointers are useful for later reading after the buffer is overwritten.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: ***Doesn't this code seem a little more confusing than it should be,*** Eventually you will learn c++ and you will use container classes instead of manually creating dynamic arrays like this.

Comment: _"code provided by the teacher"_...  So sad :(

Comment: @Chad -- She's an assembly language and fortran expert. The C++ she threw together for us here was more of a favor for people who have no Fortran background. I have neither so I figured the C++ would be easier to understand, but now I'm thinking this isn't proper C++

Comment: BTW, Yes there will be garbage in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To me, it looks like this will create a bunch of garbage based on whatever was in memory before b was created...

Correct, the value of the `float`s in the array are not initialized.

> There is no initialization of b[0][0]

None of the `b[0][y]` for all `y` in `[0,n*nCols)` are initialized.

> so it seems like this will generate unpredictable output.

Only if you don't initialize those values before you use them. There is no output at all in the code that you show. In fact, the values are not even read in the shown code.

Well, there appears to be a typo in the original code:

```
b[j] = b[j-1] + n;
```

Should be

```
b[j] = b[j-1] + nCols;
```

The code is correct assuming that bug is fixed. Otherwise, if `n` is greater than `nCols`, there will be a buffer overflow.

> So b is an array of size n pointers to arrays of size nCols

Not quite. `b[0]` points to an array that contains all `n*nCols` values. The rest of `b[x]`, `x` in `[1,n)` point to different locations of the same array. But indeed, you can use the pointers as if they pointed to arrays of size `nCols`.

Comment: Thanks very much. This is a great answer, I wish I could accept both yours and Chad's.

Comment: Wait a minute, yours I think is more correct -- I'm seeing something in your answer that Chad might have missed... Your note about the typo... `b[j] = b[j-1] + nCols;` is apparently using pointer arithmetic to assign pointers within the larger array... Interesting. Good catch on the typo.

Comment: @tmsimont Pointer arithmetic is exactly what's going on with the line.

Answer (score 2):

The code is both confusing, and probably (it's hard to tell the intent) incorrect.

```
// we create an arry of float*
float **b = new float*[n];

// assume n is 3
//    b[0] is a float*, value not explicitly set
//    b[1] is a float*, value not explicitly set
//    b[2] is a float*, value not explicitly set

// b[0] then creates an array of float, assume nCols is 2
b[0] = new float[n*nCols]; 

//    b[0] is a float*, pointing to an array of 6 (3*2) floats
//    b[1] is a float*, value not explicitly set
//    b[2] is a float*, value not explicitly set

// we then iterate the rest and assign values (apparently incorrectly)
for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
{
    // b[1] = b[1-1] + 3
    b[j] = b[j-1] + n;
}
```

The canonical way to do this in C++ is to use a `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> matrix;

matrix.resize(n);  // resize to the number of rows

for(auto& row : matrix)
{
    row.resize(nCols);  // resize each row to the number of columns
                        // std::vector::resize will default initialize
                        // the floats created here
}
```

Now you can access it as you expect:

```
matrix[2][1] = 6;
```

In this case, the memory layout is non-contiguous, which for large matrices can be burdensome, as the different parts need to be fetched from memory that may not be in cache.  It basically looks like this -- the "addresses" are just there to indicate that each value in a row is contiguous, and each column is contiguous, but there is a disconnect where the entire structure is NOT.

```
matrix[0] - some address, assume 0
   row[0] - some address, assume 64
   row[1] - some address, assume 72
   row[2] - some address, assume 80
matrix[1] - some address, assume 8
   row[0] - some address, assume 128
   ...
matrix[1] - some address, assume 16
   row[0] - some address, assume 256
```

For a true matrix (where both the rows and columns are fixed), you can use a single vector and use multiplication to get/set the appropriate value.

A 2*3 matrix will have 6 elements.

```
  std::vector<float> matrix(6);  // create a vector with 6 floats

  size_t row = 1, col = 2;
  matrix[row*col] = 3;
```

In this case, all of the data is kept in contiguous memory.

Comment: awesome, thanks. Does that leave the memory of matrix identical to memory occupied by what the original code should have created (except done correctly)? I ask because we then pass the address of b[0] to MPI. I wonder if using vector would affect what MPI expects when we tell it it's receiving an array of floats at b[0]'s address

Comment: It's similar, yes.  But any time code uses dynamic allocation (such as the original example, and here (`std::vector` uses dynamic allocation internally), the memory layout is not always easy to explain.  The final edit (the single vector) has the simplest layout, as it is all contiguous.

Comment: Thanks very much, Chad. I wish I could assign more than one correct answer. I had to give it to user2079303 because he caught something about the way the pointers were being assigned

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to try to predict the intention of the teacher just from this piece of code. Here are some thoughts about arrays that may help you in your understanding.

Dynamic arrays are indistinguishable from pointers. A pointer points to a memory address. A dynamic array is a pointer to the beginning of the array, and an associated length (which you have to know and keep somewhere).

In your provided code sample, where you have:

```
float **b = new float*[n];
```

You are defining a new array of memory. The size of the array in bytes, is the size of `float*` (a pointer to a float) times `n`, and the address of that array is stored in `b`, which can hold addresses to float pointers. None of the positions of the new array are initialized yet, and contain garbage as you mentioned.

Afterwards where you have:

```
b[0] = new float[n*nCols];
```

The thing happening there is that you are requesting a new array of memory. The size of this new array in bytes, is the size of a `float` times `n*nCols`, and the address of that array is stored in `b[0]`. None of the positions of this new array are initialized yet.

Finally, the rest of the code provided initializes the rest of positions of `b`, using the values of previously initialized positions. So `b[1]` is initialized to something that depends on `b[0]`, `b[2]` is initialized to something that depends on `b[1]`, and so on.

```
for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) b[j] = b[j-1] + n;
```

Now lets drill down that a little. `b[j-1] + n` is adding the integer value `n` to the expression `b[j-1]`, which is of type `float*`. When you add an integer to a memory address, you are basically defining a new memory address that points to the original memory address plus the integer value times the size of the pointer. This is known as pointers arithmetic.

```
b[1] = b[0] + n
```

This assigns in `b[1]` a shifted part of the array in `b[0]`. So basically `b[1][X] == b[0+n][X]` will be true for any value of `X`. That is true, because `b[1]` points to the same memory address than `b[0+n]`.

I don't know if the code provided by your professor is correct. We would need the whole code and the description of the problem being solved. The fragment of the code you provided only created 2 arrays, and initialized just 1 of them. The second (the big array of floats) remains un-initialized with this code.

Hope this helps you in your understanding.

Comment: Well said. This is exactly what I realized after user2079303 provided his answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code is perfectly fine, but yes it is a little confusing. Instead of making an allocate call for every subarray, your teacher allocated the memory once and distribute it across different rows.

The shape of b that you created is fine, but yes the allocated memory contains garbage. To initialize it with zero you can do following,

```
float **b = new float*[n]; //create local matrix
b[0] = new float[n*nCols] {0.0f}; // this line changed
for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) b[j] = b[j-1] + n;
```

or you can use following to initialize with default value,

```
float **b = new float*[n]; //create local matrix
b[0] = new float[n*nCols](); // this line changed
for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) b[j] = b[j-1] + n;
```